# Stuck in macOS Utilities while reinstalling macOS

Tags: macbook-pro, install

I’m trying to reinstall my macOS, but now I’m stuck in macOS Utilities. And when I want to reinstall macOS Sierra I get "Permission denied":

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the suggestions [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/cant-reinstall-macos-from-recovery-mode-wont-allow-me-to-select-system-disk.2294294/) help?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Macintosh HD" instead of "Macintosh HD - Data"?

Comment: Is this running from Recovery?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run the Installer from an already running OS.

You need to run the installer through External Media (e.g USB)

Run the Installer USB as a startup Disk. You can Google how to do it.